# Why the result of this code is duplicated?

Tags: c

**Why the result is duplicated**

Hi, I made this code and what I want is Create Union type called family_name it shall have two members first_name and last_name. The two members are array of characters with same size 30. Try to write string in the first member
first_name, then print the second member last_name also print the size of the union.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

union family_name
{
   char first_name[30];
   char last_name[30];
};

int main( )
{
   union family_name Family;        

   strcpy( Family.first_name, "Monjed");
   strcpy( Family.last_name,  "Salih");

   printf( "First name : %s\n", Family.first_name);
   printf( "Last name : %s\n", Family.last_name);
   printf("Size of union = %d bytes", sizeof(Family));


   return 0;
}
```

**Result:**

```sql
 First name : Salih
 Last name : Salih
 Size of union = 30 bytes
```

Comment: In a union, all members *share* the same memory. Perhaps you should use a `struct` instead?

Comment: Do you know the difference between `struct` and `union`? The members of your `union` share the same memory, as can be seen from `Size of union = 30 bytes`

Comment: I have to use union, and I can't change that.

Comment: Then the assignment makes no sense, except to demonstrate the behaviour of a `union`.

Comment: What is your actual assignment or exercise? Why are you limited to using only a union? If it's an assignment/exercise from school or a text-book or similar, then please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete assignment text into your question, including all limitations and requirements.

Comment: Also note that the `sizeof` operator returns a value of the type `size_t`. To print such values with `printf` you need to use the `%zu` format specifier. Mismatching formatting specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: 6. Create Union type called family_name it shall have two members first_name and last_name. The two members are array of characters with same size 30. Try to write string in the first member 
first_name, then print the second member last_name also print the size of the union.

Comment: As said by @WeatherVane, that looks like an assignment in understanding the behavior of unions, and how the memory is shared. Whatever data you write last, will be the only data available. Please spend some more time with your text-books, and don't skip classes.

Comment: Please read the assignment requirement more carefully.  It says "Try to write string in the **first member** first_name, then print the **second member** last_name." So the exercise is to show how the `union` works, not to actually store *both* names - because it can't.

Comment: This assignment is not mine and I am doing it for someone.

Comment: Your code does not do what the task requires.

Comment: What will this other "someone" learn from not doing the exercise? What are you getting in return?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , I don't want anything in return because he's my brother.

Comment: @WeatherVane I made some edits to my question
I also made modifications to the code. Is this correct for the requirements?

Comment: My answer showed what was asked. I've changed the question back to the original, as SO is not a "rolling tutorial".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the exercise is to show how a `union` works. The posted code does not do what the assignment asked, and here is the corrected code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

union family_name
{
   char first_name[30];
   char last_name[30];
};

int main(void)                                           // conforming
{
   union family_name Family;        
   strcpy( Family.first_name, "Monjed");                 // write first member
   printf( "Last name : %s\n", Family.last_name);        // read second member
   printf("Size of union = %zu bytes", sizeof(Family));  // correct format spec
   return 0;
}
```

This shows that the data is shared by both members, and the size of the `union` is the size of its largest member.

```
Last name : Monjed
Size of union = 30 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use structure instead of union.

```
struct family_name
{
   char first_name[30];
   char last_name[30];
};
```

union members share the same memory (ie will have the same context in your case as you have the same type of members).

Comment: Create Union type called family_name it shall have two members first_name and last_name. The two members are array of characters with same size 30. Try to write string in the first member 
first_name, then print the second member last_name also print the size of the union.

I can do this using union?

Comment: @OsmanSalih I do not understand what you mean. I do not understand the whole comment

Comment: The solution is not to use `struct` but to read the assigment requirement carefully, which does not require to store *both* names. It is "write to name 1, report name 2".